# PHP preg_match return false even if condition match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using *preg_match* to verify an input :

```
$string = 'test';

if (preg_match ('/[^-a-z\d]/i', $string))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Well I can not understand why it return **false** here !

Am I missing something ?

Shouldn't it return **true** ?

**The solution :**

```
(preg_match ('/^[-a-z\d]*$/i', $string))
```

Comment: could you please add some sample $string values for which this code is failing

Comment: It's data submitted using a form with post method, input type text @ShivaniKatukota When I use alfa-numeric or dash in form field, it return false, while when I use other characters, it return true !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tyr this

```
(preg_match ('/^[-A-Za-z\d]*$/', $string))
```

Comment: If you pass special character then it will return false. I checked.

Comment: I will try again :)

Comment: If you want to match everything inside the square brackets, add `+` to the end as well: `/^[-a-z\d]+/i`. Without it, it'll only match the first matching character (`t`)

Comment: Well, at least I think I know what the problem is ! it just verify the first character of the string and return ! how can I verify the whole string ?

Comment: I have updated the regular expression. which will accept only alfa numeric and dash character.

Comment: That's what I want, thank you so much :) does '*$' mean all characters in string ?

Comment: "*" means 0 or more characters and "$" means end of string. If you want ot expect atleast one character should be there then we can use "+" in place of "*".

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So `preg_match()` can return `0`, `1`, or `false` it is probably safer to do a strict check that the result equals `1`, i.e.

```
abstract class Pattern 
{
    /** @const int */
    const TEXT_MATCH = 1;

    /**
     * @param string $pattern regex pattern to match against
     * @param string $string  the text string to search
     * 
     * @return bool 
     */
    public static function match(string $pattern, string $string): bool
    {
        return preg_match($pattern, $string) === self::TEXT_MATCH;
    }
}
```

Primarily the bit you're interested in is this

```
preg_match($pattern, $string) === 1;
```

If you then use it:

```
$result = Pattern::match('/[^-a-z\d]/i', 'test');
var_dump($result); // false
```

The string doesn't pass the check. If that doesn't resolve your issue we're going to need to see a few examples of strings you are passing through that are always passing. It's probably also worth explaining what you want the regex to match against, because that could be part of the issue also.